# Twitter ID handle history. Is there a way to get old handle a twitter ID used? Via the API or some other means

Tags: api, twitter, handle

I've been using the twitter API for a bit now, and I'm curious if there's a way to retrieve old twitter handles from accounts that have changed theirs?

If there isn't one via the API, does anyone know of any databases available (either free or paid) that have this option?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this, and it would strictly speaking be against Twitter's API terms to provide a database like this, since deleted, suspended or private accounts etc would need to be removed from those data stores to be compliant.